# Nock - how to log the status of each request?

Tags: nock

I would like to be able to see each request that an interceptor has intercepted and see whether it has responded or is pending. I am using `scope.persist(true)` for each interceptor. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scope`s emit events when an `Interceptor` is matched to a request and when that `Interceptor` replies with a payload. 
https://github.com/nock/nock#events

The callback for each of those events gets passed the `Interceptor` as an arg.

I'm not entirely sure what the ask is around "see whether it has responded or is pending", but something like this should get you going:

```
const scope = nock('http://example.test')
  .get('/')
  .reply(200)

scope.on('request', (req, interceptor) => {
  console.log('interceptor matched request', interceptor.uri)
});
scope.on('replied', (req, interceptor) => {
  console.log('response replied with nocked payload', interceptor.uri)
});
```

Comment: When I implement the above suggestion, I get `TypeError: scope.on is not a function` if I do not immediately state it after `scope = nock(baseUrl);`, i.e. if I do `scope.persist();scope.delay(delay);` before `scope.on(...);` then i see the above error.

Comment: Odd. `delay` is on the interceptor, not on the scope. So I would expect the error there. https://github.com/nock/nock#delay-the-response